# How do I add an integer to each element of an array bash?

Tags: arrays, bash

I would like to add 1 to each element of a bash array. Say I have an array:

```
array1=(5 1 7 9 4)
```

What I would like is to do ideally is this:

```
echo ${array2[@]}

5 6 1 2 7 8 9 10 4 5
```

So that each number is followed by its consecutive number. But I wasn't sure if this was possible so failing that I wanted to just generate the array:

```
echo ${array3[@]}

6 4 2 8 10 5
```

I can achieve the former with a for loop:

```
for i in ${array1[@]}; do array2+=($i `expr $i + 1`); done
```

But this is very time-consuming (my array has 20 million elements) so I was just wondering whether there was a more direct way of doing this?

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do? How did you get 20 million elements in your bash array? What's the logic to generate 2nd array from 1st array (in words)?

Comment: A Bash for loop over 20M elements isn't exactly a speedy experience, are you sure Bash is the right tool for what you're trying to do?

Comment: To start, use `$((i + 1))` instead of `expr`.

Comment: what are you going to do with a 20 (40?) million item array? any sort of `bash` looping construct on that volume of values is going to take a looong time to process; you may want to spend some time testing your current process/design from a performance perspective ... with a view towards possibly rethinking what tools/languages are going to be more performant

Comment: `my array has 20 million elements` Everything in Bash with will be extremely slow. Bash is slow. Firstly, export the 20 million array to a file. Then write a program in something that is fast to work on that file, like C++ or Rust. `But this is very time-consuming` Have you actually tested the code that you posted on 20 million elements array? Are you sure that specifically this loop, and not creating the array is slow?

Comment: Invoking `expr` is **much** slower than POSIX-standardized shell-builtin math such as `$(( i + 1 ))`. More than 100x slower, easily.

Answer (score 0):

For handling 20 million elements, you can't manipulate too much.  As someone else said, shell doesn't seem the best tool because interpreting is slow, but also because doubtful it would allow that many elements into a single array.  [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) would be much faster.

The solution proposed below is an attempt to meet your unexpressed needs, processing each item from an input stream, individually and independently, and pushing that result to output immediately, not creating a memory-resident monster unless you absolutely want to keep it and process that subsequently for logic in the AWK "END" segment.

```
#!/bin/sh

BASE=`basename "$0" ".sh" `
SAMPLE_INPUT_STREAM="${BASE}.input"

cat >"${SAMPLE_INPUT_STREAM}" <<-!EnDoFiNpUt
5
1
7
9
4
!EnDoFiNpUt

awk 'BEGIN{
    split( "", shiftPairing ) ;
    pos=0 ;
}
{
    pos++ ;

#   ### Memory-resident approach
#   shiftPairing[pos,1]=$1 ;
#   shiftPairing[pos,2]=$1+1 ;
#   printf("[%d|%s|%s]\n", pos, shiftPairing[pos,1], shiftPairing[pos,2] ) ;

    ### Memory-avoiding approach
    printf("[%d|%s|%s]\n", pos, $1, $1+1 ) ;

#}END{
#   print "\nPost-Processing ..." ;
#   for( i=1 ; i<= pos ; i++ ){
#       printf("[%d|%s|%s]\n", pos, shiftPairing[pos,1], shiftPairing[pos,2] ) ;
#   } ;
}' "${SAMPLE_INPUT_STREAM}"
```

The session output would look like this:

```
ericthered@OasisMega1:/0__WORK$ ./test_44.sh
[1|5|6]
[2|1|2]
[3|7|8]
[4|9|10]
[5|4|5]
ericthered@OasisMega1:/0__WORK$
```

OR ... for the memory-intensive logic using post-processing:

```
ericthered@OasisMega1:/0__WORK$ ./test_44.sh
[1|5|6]
[2|1|2]
[3|7|8]
[4|9|10]
[5|4|5]

Post-Processing ...
[1|5|6]
[2|1|2]
[3|7|8]
[4|9|10]
[5|4|5]
ericthered@OasisMega1:/0__WORK$
```

That reporting keeps the genomic sequencing number aligned with the two strand identifiers adjacent to each other, in case there is need for positional searching in the resulting output.  That could be redirected where you want it.  In this example, I've used square brackets, but for my own personal usage, I always use vertical bars as a single identifiable delimiter.  That can be modified in the printf statement.

Answer (score 0):

*While sticking to pure bash*, the obvious performance enhancement is to drop the subshell invoking the external command `expr`:

```
for i in "${array1[@]}"; do array2+=("$i" "$(( i + 1 ))"); done
```

Every subshell requires `fork()`ing a new process. Every invocation of `expr`, *or any other command that isn't built into the shell*, requires `execve()`'ing a separate executable. Both these things are slow enough that they should never be done in a performance-sensitive tight loop.

That said, I second the proposal that bash is a poorly-chosen language for handling the volume of data you're trying to process. Rust, Julia, Go, awk... there are lots of other choices.